# How do I show custom 'Logged in' welcome messages based on customer tags? (Shopify/Liquid)

Tags: shopify

I have a working script that i gathered from the internet (I am no expert) but I'm not sure if it works well. But it seems to work fine though.

```
{% if customer %}
{% assign customer == 'new'}
{% for tag in customer.tags %}
{% if tag contains "wholesale" %}
{%assign customer == 'wholesale' %}
{% endif %}
{% if customer != 'wholesale' %}
  <span>Wholsaler</span>
{% endif %}
{% else %}
  <span>Visitor</span>
{% endif %}
```

But now i have an issue that i can't solve, my boss wanted me to have the liquid script change into something like the following below:

1. If the visitor is "Not" logged-in, a message will appear "You are not logged-in"
2. If the visitor is Logged-in as a "Retail", a message will appear "Welcome Retailer"
3. If the visitor is Logged-in as a "Wholesaler", a message will appear "Welcome Wholesaler"

I could not get the third script to work, if there's anyone who can kindly solve the issue I have, please point me to the right direction or a proper way of scripting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is trying to overwrite the `customer` variable with something that is not a customer object.  You will need to create a new variable name to make your script work.  For example, if there is a logged in `customer` you then set that variable equal to the word `new`.  The word `new` doesn't have any tags associated with it, so nothing will happen in the for-loop.  (Additionally, it doesn't look like you closed your forloop with an `endfor`)

One other suggestion I would make is to use the `contains` keyword rather than a forloop to check the customer tags.  `contains` can be used on simple arrays (such as a list of tags) to check if any of the tags is exactly equal to the supplied value and is cleaner and more efficient than a forloop, especially if a customer has a lot of tags.

The final code might look something like this:

```
{% if customer %} 
  {% comment %} Shopper is logged in, but are they special? {% endcomment %}
  {% assign lowercase_tags = customer.tags | join: ',' | downcase | split: ',' %}
  {% if lowercase_tags contains 'wholesale' %}
    {% assign customer_message = 'Welcome, Wholesaler!' %}
  
  {% comment %}OPTIONAL: We can use one or more elsif (Liquid's version of "else if") statements to check for any other special tags, if desired. {% endcomment %}
  {% elsif lowercase_tags contains 'some-other-special-tag' %}
    {% assign customer_message = 'Super Buddy' %}
  
  {% else %} 
    {% comment %} This will be the message for logged-in customers without any special tags {% endcomment %}
    {% assign customer_message = 'Logged in as  ' | append: customer.name %}

  {% endif %}
  {% comment %} Print the appropriate welcome message {% endcomment %}
  <span class="welcome-message">{{ customer_message }}</span>

{% else %}
  {% comment %} Customer is not logged in {% endcomment %}
  <span class="log-in-prompt">You are not logged in</span>
{% endif %}
```

Bonus points: Rather than hard-code the above customer messages into the template files, Shopify gives you language files in your `locales` folder. Putting any language text into your store's main language file (typically `en.default.json` unless you have changed languages) will then let you edit that text in the future by using the "Customize Language" option for that theme. Reference: https://shopify.dev/tutorials/develop-theme-localization-use-translation-keys

Comment: Than you so much, but how can i get rid of the retailer since its no longer needed, i just got a call from my boss and he wanted it to be just a regular login person with no Tag instead of a retailer? is that possible to do, im sorry i am very new in shopify, thank you for answering my post, its working really good, the only thing that has been change is to get rid of the "Retailer" and replace it with a "Customer does not contain a tag"

Comment: So things have changed :( this is now what my wanted and its final: :(

Comment: Does the new edit give you what you need to succeed?

Comment: First of, thank you so much!

Yes, but im going crazy because he wants this to be like this:

 1.  If the visitor is "Not" logged-in, a message will appear "You are not logged-in"
 2.  If the visitor is Logged-in that has "No Tag" a message will appear "Welcome Back"
 3.  If the visitor is Logged-in as a "Wholesaler", a message will appear "Welcome Wholesaler"

its driving me crazy i can't solve number "2"

Comment: Hmmm. Possibly worth noting is that `contains` is a case-sensitive check. Can you confirm that the word we're using to check with is exactly equal to the tag name?

Comment: I added a line to turn the tag array into an array of lowercase strings, which would remove the case-sensitivity bit (if that helps?)

Comment: Oh! I read too quickly and didn't check which one was #2 in your comment. `2. If the visitor is Logged-in that has "No Tag" a message will appear "Welcome Back"` - You should just have to set the message following `This will be the message for logged-in customers without any special tags` to be the appropriate message. (I used `Logged in as` above, feel free to change that to anything you need it to say)

Comment: Its working but can we do this instead "  {% else %} 
    {% assign customer_message = 'Logged in as  ' | append: customer.name %}" like we prefer to have it as a custom message <span>Welcome Back!</span> thank you so much for everything!

Comment: Aye, change that message to anything you need! If you don't need the name, just omit the `| append: customer.name` part.  Whatever the `customer_message` gets `assign`'d to be is what will be printed into the following `span` tag.

Comment: Hi Dave! Thank you so much! you are my savior!